# MultiThreading com pool de conexão "Duplicate database name 'XXX'"

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Estou desenvolvendo um serviço para funcionar com multithread de um código fonte antigo que usa BDE e DBX, pra que cada thread tenha sua propria conexão eu desenvolvi um singleton com pool de conexão a qual ele usa o método **GetCurrentThreadID** para localizar no pool se a conexão já existe e se não existir eu crio

---

```
     if not Assigned(m_PoolConexoes)
        then m_PoolConexoes := TObjectList.Create(True);

      for i := 0 to Pred(m_PoolConexoes.Count) do
      begin
        if TSingletonConexao(m_PoolConexoes[i]).FThreadID = GetCurrentThreadId then
        begin
          Result := TSingletonConexao(m_PoolConexoes[i]);
          Break;
        end;
      end;

      if not Assigned(Result) then
      begin
        Result := TSingletonConexao.Create();
        m_PoolConexoes.Add( Result );
        TMisc.LogEventViewer(9999,'Quantidade de Conexoes Ativas: '+ IntToStr(m_PoolConexoes.Count), 9999);
      end;
```

Ao finalizar a thread no **OnTerminate** eu limpo a conexão pelo método abaixo:

```
class procedure TSingletonConexao.FreeInstancia;
var
  i: Integer;
begin

  TMisc.LogEventViewer(9996,'Iniciando o FreeInstancia de conexão da thread : '+ IntToStr(GetCurrentThreadId), 9996);
  if Assigned(m_PoolConexoes) then
  begin
    for i := 0 to Pred(m_PoolConexoes.Count) do
    begin
      if TSingletonConexao(m_PoolConexoes[i]).FThreadID = GetCurrentThreadId then
      begin
        m_PoolConexoes.Remove( m_PoolConexoes[i] ); // Ao remover da lista, o obj é destruído...
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  TMisc.LogEventViewer(9996,'Quantidade de Conexoes Ativas: '+ IntToStr(m_PoolConexoes.Count), 9996);
end;
```

Destroy:

```
destructor TSingletonConexao.Destroy;
begin
  SafeFree( FQuery );

  if SafeAssigned( FConexaoDBX )
    then FConexaoDBX.Close;
  SafeFree( FConexaoDBX );

  if SafeAssigned( FConexaoBDE )
    then FConexaoBDE.Close;
  SafeFree( FConexaoBDE );

  TMisc.LogEventViewer(9996,'Encerrando uma Conexão com o ThreadID: '+ IntToStr(FThreadID), 9996);
  inherited Destroy;
end;
```

O problema é que como estou em loop, por algum motivo desconhecido por mim, a conexão não está sendo destruída e ocorre o erro **"Duplicate database name 'XXX'"**. 
Alguém poderia me dar uma luz de como resolver isso? Parece que a conexão está se mantendo mesmo tendo sido destruída (estranho).

**Obs**: Pra criar as conexões, eu faço o seguinte, ao logar no sistema já existe uma conexão aberta, então eu crio o objeto e passo os atributos da conexão aberta alterando apenas o **Name** e o **DatabaseName**, colocando o nome da conexão original concatenado com **GetCurrentThreadID**

```
  FThreadID := GetCurrentThreadId();
  with dmConexaoDireta.dbAplicacao do
  begin
    FConexaoBDE := TDatabase.Create(nil);
    FConexaoBDE.DatabaseName := DatabaseName +'_'+ IntToStr(FThreadID);
    FConexaoBDE.DriverName := DriverName;
    FConexaoBDE.AliasName := AliasName;
    FConexaoBDE.Exclusive := Exclusive;
    FConexaoBDE.HandleShared := HandleShared;
    FConexaoBDE.KeepConnection := KeepConnection;
    FConexaoBDE.LoginPrompt := LoginPrompt;
    FConexaoBDE.Name := FConexaoBDE.DatabaseName;
    FConexaoBDE.Params.Text := Params.Text;
    FConexaoBDE.ReadOnly := ReadOnly;
    FConexaoBDE.SessionName := SessionName;
    FConexaoBDE.TransIsolation := TransIsolation;
    FConexaoBDE.Connected := True;
  end;
```

**Obs2**: Já tentei criar o TDatabase com owner **Application** e agora eu coloquei **nil**.

**Obs3**: Os métodos SafeAssigned e SafeFree são métodos que uso pra não estourar erro.

Comment: Complicado, mas `TDatabase.Create(nil)` de certa forma esta errado, pois fica tecnicamente *impossível* localiza-lo, pois, criou-se `nil`, volte para *Self ou Application* que já é o caminho certo.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Júnior, tanto _Self_ quanto _Application_ não resolvem o problema. Estou procurando ver se consigo resolver isso de outra maneira, sem ter a necessidade de ficar destruindo e criando várias conexões.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi essa questão fazendo com que minha thread não fosse finalizada a cada ciclo, ao invés disso eu coloquei a fila em singleton e fiz com que a thread tenha a inteligência de procurar o proximo registro na fila e, caso não encontre, aguardar 3 segundos para procurar novamente.